# Toggle клик SideBar

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap

У меня есть 3 компонента: Header, SideBar, Talbe. Все они рендерятся на App.vue.
Как при клике в кнопке Header показать SideBar (toggle click).

Answer (score 0):

Через Emit + Listener.
В Header.vue

```
@click="emit..."
```

В App.vue добавить Listener, который бы вызывал метод sibebarIsVisible, это просто моё название метода.

Затем,

```
<SideBar v-if="sidebarIsVisible"></SideBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное ответ уже не актуален, но напишу, может потом кому то будет полезно.

1. Создаем в App.vue свойство `showSidebar: false`, которое будет отвечать за показ компонента SideBar
2. Задаем компоненте SideBar показ в зависимости от свойства `showSidebar`:

   ```
   <SideBar v-if="showSidebar"/>
   ```
3. В компоненте Header вешаем событие на кнопку

   ```
   <button @click="onClick">Click</button>
   ```
4. Это событие эмитит событие `onClick` родителю:

   ```
   onClick() {
     this.$emit('onClick');
   }
   ```
5. В App.vue на компоненте Header принимаем событие из компоненты и изменяем свойство `showSidebar`:

   ```
   <Header @onClick="showSidebar = !showSidebar"/>
   ```

Готово.